# Disconnecting Stepper Motor While Active

Tags: mosfet, relay, stepper-motor

I've been playing with using one stepper motor driver to control multiple bipolar stepper motors (one at a time).

I've found disabling the stepper motor, using a relay array to switch to another stepper works fine.

If I don't do this, and try and switch while the stepper is powered, it can cause the stepper motor driver to "lockup" and need to be powered down to reset it and get it working again. I assume this is from back EMF of the stepper driver, and understand from googling I could kill the driver doing this.

I've found using two steppers in parallel gets around this problem, basically a second stepper to handle the back EMF of disconnecting the first stepper. So one stepper is always connected, during the relay switch over, then two are connected when the switch over happens. This isn't optimal as it halves the current to the stepper I want to drive.

**Question 1:**

Could I use two inductors in place of the always connected stepper motor, to essentially fake what the second (always connected) stepper motor is doing?

**Question 2:**

Alternatively, instead of relays, what about using MOSFETs and allowing a crossover period between two stepper motors. So there is never a time a stepper motor is not connected, but allowing a short period that two steppers are active, before the first stepper is disconnected.

Comment: You’ve not told us what the stepper motor driver is - they’re not all the same. Realistically, with the cost of the average stepper driver module, why try shenanigans? By trying to cut corners, you create a problem, which you try to solve but that creates another problem. You expend more time and effort doing work-arounds than just simply having a motor driver per motor. Sometimes it pays not to be too clever. I frequently slap myself when I fall into that trap.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. The usage is to allow any number of extruders on a 3d printer without soldering pins onto the step / dir of the stepper driver internally. Which is how I currently do it. Just thinking of a way to do it without modifying original hardware  

Since the x/y/z and E movements need to be synchronised, you need the output of the from the xyz controller to also do the E movement. 

Drivers can be any type of driver. I'm using A4988 and various TMC flavours idea is to make a driver independent solution.

Comment: The driver chips you mention should have a means of disabling the motor drive so that you can switch the motors safely.

Comment: That's currently what I do as per my original question. But most 3d printers have 1 enable pin for all steppers, and trying to not disable xyz to be able to disable e. As that can cause layer shifts

Comment: You might want to think about using clutches or meshing/unmeshing gears to selectively couple the extruded to one motor.